# django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint

Tags: django, django-models

I have Country model

```
from django.db import models 

class Country(models.Model):
    country = models.CharField(max_length = 20, primary_key=True)
    country_id = models.IntegerField()
```

I uploaded some data in Country table with following custom management command

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from data.models import Country
import json
from .extract_country import extracting



get_parsed_json = extracting() 

def store_data():
    for key, value in get_parsed_json['api']['countries'].items():
        country_id_field = key
        country_name = value 
        One_country = Country.objects.create(country_id = country_id_field , country = country_name)
        One_country.save()
        print(One_country)



class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, **options):
        extracting()
        store_data()
```

Now i am trying to upload to the Country table extended data which contain the same countries and another but when i am trying to upload data i get the following error. Here is my full traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util
s.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "data_co
untry_name_04df4fc7_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (country)=(Algeria) already exists.


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\
base.py", line 353, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\project\forecasting\data\management\comma
nds\upload_country.py", line 23, in handle
    store_data()
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\project\forecasting\data\management\comma
nds\upload_country.py", line 14, in store_data
    One_country = Country.objects.create(country_id = country_id_field , country
 = country_name)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manage
r.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.
py", line 413, in create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 718, in save
    force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 748, in save_base
    updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, upda
te_fields)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 831, in _save_table
    result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.p
y", line 869, in _do_insert
    using=using, raw=raw)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manage
r.py", line 82, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.
py", line 1136, in _insert
    return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\co
mpiler.py", line 1289, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util
s.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util
s.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._e
xecute)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util
s.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util
s.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", li
ne 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "D:\Python\my_projects\forecast\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\util
s.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "
data_country_name_04df4fc7_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (country)=(Algeria) already exists.
```

I found that is very frequent problem for django users but didnt find how to fix it. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that you try to create `County` with same `county` name as it's your primary key.
Try to use `get_or_create()`:

```
def store_data():
    for key, value in get_parsed_json['api']['countries'].items():
        country_id_field = key
        country_name = value 
        one_country, created = Country.objects.update_or_create(
            country_id=country_id_field
            defaults={'country': country_name},
        )
        # one_country.save() <- no need to save after create or get_or_create method.
        print(one_country)
```

Comment: i tried your approach but i get the same error but now with country Italy here is traceback  
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "
data_country_name_04df4fc7_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (country)=(Italy) already exists.

Comment: I think it could happen if for some reasone id were different. I changed a bit my code and added `defaults` in `get_or_create` but query it only by `country_name`. Please try again.

Comment: it's worked but now i in my country_id has dubplicated values for example i have country Italy with country_id = 26 and Malaysia with the same country_id

Comment: Seems like some id's are same for different countries in your data. For that reason use `update_or_create` method as I edited my answer.

Comment: I am extract data from API and country_id is unique for each country

Comment: Yes, but you added country name as `primary_key` but not a `country_id`

Comment: Now it's worked. I added country_name like primary_key because country name need me in anather table like foreign key. Thank you for your help

Comment: If it helped please mark my answer as a solution. Good luck!

Comment: I did. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The primary key must be unique, if there is an instance with the key "Algeria" already exists, you cannot create a second instance with the same key.

Instead of:

```
One_country = Country.objects.create(country_id = country_id_field , country = country_name)
```

You could use [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

```
# ...
One_country, created = Country.objects.get_or_create(country=country_name)
One_country.country_id = country_id_field
One_country.save()
# ...
```

Comment: I tried your code but get the same error but with another Country. Here is past of traceback  
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "
data_country_name_04df4fc7_uniq"
DETAIL:  Key (country)=(Italy) already exists.

Comment: I tried insert this code 
        `one_country, created = Country.objects.get_or_create(
            country=country_name,
            defaults={'country_id': country_id_field},
        )`
  and after it in my database dublicate country_id fields and now i am can not to try your aproach

Comment: Sorry, I got country and country_id mixed up. It should definitely work now.